# Android: horizontal scroll in tabhost

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, android-tabhost

I created a tabhost in my activity in this way:

```
mTabHost = getTabHost();
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Phone").setIndicator("TELEFONO", iconContact).setContent(R.id.linear1));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("MAPPE", iconMap).setContent(R.id.scroll2));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Cam").setIndicator("WEBCAM", iconWebcam).setContent(R.id.scrollWebcam)); //metto il tab per le webcam
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Setting").setIndicator("IMPOSTAZ.", iconImpostaz).setContent(R.id.scrollImp));
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

but now the number of tabs required is incrising, so I need to scroll the tabs horizontally. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This library is exactly what you are looking for :

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator